# Where are Minecraft: Education Edition files stored?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

We all know where Minecraft: Java Edition files are stored (Windows 10):

```
C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves
```

It's a little harder to find, but Bedrock Edition players can find their world saves here:

```
C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

Surprisingly, there is no documentation online found on where files are stored for Minecraft: Education Edition.

I would expect, since MCEE is based off of MCBE, the files are stored as another folder in `Packages`:

```
C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftEducationEdition
```

or something of the like.

But I don't see an extra folder for MCEE there.

If not there, then where?

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, I found the MCEE world files in a similar location to the MCJE world files instead, at the following folder path:

```
C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Roaming\Minecraft Education Edition\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

Just like Bedrock Edition, MCEE doesn't show the level names on the folders, you'll need to open each folder's inner file named `levelname.txt` to reveal which world that is.

From there, refer to the Bedrock Edition NBT editor posts for help.

Answer (score 2):

I found my Education Edition worlds in:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftEducationEdition_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

(change username to your username in Windows)

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you want to use them in Bedrock then it will not let you

Comment: Hm, this is interesting. Could it be that something has changed? If so, I'll have to mark my answer as outdated.

Comment: My files are at this location as well

Answer (score 0):

I found mine under `Windows (C:)` (I have a Windows 11), then `Program Files x86`. Then I clicked `Microsoft Studios` and it was there.
I renamed Microsoft Studios to Minecraft for future easy file finding.

Comment: Don't change the folder names in Program Files, as it might cause Minecraft to stop being able to run!

Answer (score -1):

MCEE has its com.mojang folder at the location

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftEducationEdition_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang
```

replace username with your windows username

Comment: What information does this convey that the other answers already don't already go over?